# Change VS2022-VSIX project Target Framework

Tags: c#, frameworks, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am learning to build extension using VSIX and I was asked to use a class library from another project that uses .net 6.0 .. I tried changing the target framework , but it was not listed .. so I clicked the option to download the dotnet-sdk-6.0.314-win-x64 , but even after installation I went back to the projects properties>Application>Target Framework and it is still not listed .. tried also to unload the project and change the TargetFrameWork version manually, but it didnt work either

any other way to change target framework of a vsix project extension?

Comment: When you create a new project, you have to choose between .NET Framework and .NET Core (.NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core). If you created a .NET Framework project, you can change that to target .NET Core. There are migration tools but it's not just changing the target framework because there are fundamental differences. I don't have VS extensions support installed so I can't check but you should see whether you can create a new extension project that targets .NET Core.

Comment: Any update of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can only reference .NET Framework and .NET Standard 2.0 packages from a VS vsix project

Answer (score 1):

> any other way to change target framework of a vsix project extension?

No, It is impossible.

From the release note of the VS2022:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes

The development framework of the Visual Studio tool itself has not changed from net framework to net core or Unified .NET, and the extension based on it is also the same, so your idea cannot be realized.